# This branch is 7 commits ahead

Tags: git, github

I have one question about github;i made some changes in my repository master,and i want it to send to some other repository master,but in repository master i have statement:"This branch is 7 commits ahead of "some repository"..."Can someone tell me what to do here?Do i just have to create new pull request for that "some repository" and wait for his answer?Or is it something else?Thanks in advance!(i am newbee to github)I tried to google,but i have not understood answers really well..:)(also,i use github desktop for creating local github repository)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but in my experience, being ahead by such-and-such commits just means that you have not pushed your commits.  So I would say probably pushing your commits and then a pull request should take care of it, without further information.

I found this online in addition, which may be more what you are looking for?:
https://www.freewayprojects.com/2011/11/solving-the-your-branch-is-ahead-of-originmaster-by-x-commits-issue-after-pulling-using-git/

Answer (score 0):

> This branch is 7 commits ahead of "some repository"..."Can someone tell me what to do here?

Means your local branch has 7 new commits that doesn't exist in other-repository *master* branch.

You should *pull* other-repository *master* branch into your local branch first (to make there is no conflict with *master*) then create *pull* request.